# How does Spring Micro service know Axon Server Port

Tags: spring-boot, event-handling, microservices, spring-cloud, axon

This entire code is available at: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/API-MicroServices-Kafka/tree/master/Microservices-CQRS-SAGA-Kafka/DiscoveryService

I have following spring-boot setup.

- Client/Postman is calling API gateway (which is also acting as load balancer).
- The API gateway and Products are spring boot application/Microservices with are registered with Eureka
- Discovery Service (Also Spring Boot Application).
- I run the applications in following order: Eureka discovery service, Products, API Gateway

In the pom.xml file for Products, I have following entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using following Axon Server: **AxonServer-4.5.5.jar** to run the Axon Server, and the **axonserver.properties** entry is as follows:

```
server.port=8026
axoniq.axonserver.name=My Axon Server
axoniq.axonserver.hostname=localhost
axoniq.axonserver.devmode.enabled=true
```

The default port for Axon server is 8024. I have tried running it on 8024, 8025, 8026 by updating the **axonserver.properties** file. The Axon server is running on localhost.

Every time I change the port in Axon server by updating the **axonserver.properties** file, the Product Microservice identifies the Axon server, even though Axon Server is not running on default port. I do not specify Axon server port in the Product Microservice.

**My Question is**: Even though I **NOT** am Specifying the port in Product Microservice, how is it that the Product Microservice identifies the correct port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missunderstanding the ports here.
Axon Server has 3 ports:

- `server.port`: HTTP port for the Axon Server console. Default is `8024`;
- `port`: gRPC port for the Axon Server node. Default is `8124`;
- `internal-port`: gRPC port for communication between Axon Server nodes within a cluster (Axon EE only). Default is `8224`.

So, a default AF application will always try to connect to an Axon Server running at `8124`, which is the gRPC port. The `8024` port is used for you to access AS dashboard (and other more specific things, like the Rest API endpoints).

To add a bit more, you can check the ref-guide for the full list of properties and configuration here: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-server/administration/admin-configuration/configuration#configuration-properties